# How to create custom items or commands for a context menu

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects, development, context-menu

I have read and searched the web for an answer, but nothing is working. so I need someone's help please.

I have an extension that implements I command, I have the method OnContextMenu(x,y) which fires on right clicking.

I would like to create a context menu, that contains 4 options, show, hide, add, delete... here is what I am doing and what I am getting

Extension Class

```c#
public class Extension1 : ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns.Extension , ICommand{
         public Extension1() {
    }

    protected override void OnStartup() {

        var mDocEvents = NEAutomation2.Application.Instance().IApplication.Document as IDocumentEvents_Event;
        if (mDocEvents != null) {
            mDocEvents.OnContextMenu += m_docEvents_OnContextMenu;
        }

WireDocumentEvents();
    }

    private void WireDocumentEvents() {

        // Named event handler
        ArcMap.Events.NewDocument += delegate() { ArcMap_NewDocument(); };

        // Anonymous event handler
        ArcMap.Events.BeforeCloseDocument += delegate() {
            // Return true to stop document from closing
            ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.IMessageDialog msgBox = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.MessageDialogClass();
            return msgBox.DoModal("BeforeCloseDocument Event", "Abort closing?", "Yes", "No", ArcMap.Application.hWnd);
        };

    }


    private bool m_docEvents_OnContextMenu(int x, int y) {
              // display context menu

       }
```

Here is the context menu class that I built

```c#
 namespace desktopExtension {
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for ContextMenu.
/// </summary>
[Guid("ca8860e1-d80c-4071-8ace-a3a47692d1ef")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ProgId("desktopExtension.ContextMenu")]
public sealed class ContextMenu : BaseMenu, IShortcutMenu {
    #region COM Registration Function(s)
    [ComRegisterFunction()]
    [ComVisible(false)]
    static void RegisterFunction(Type registerType) {
        // Required for ArcGIS Component Category Registrar support
        ArcGISCategoryRegistration(registerType);

        //
        // TODO: Add any COM registration code here
        //
    }

    [ComUnregisterFunction()]
    [ComVisible(false)]
    static void UnregisterFunction(Type registerType) {
        // Required for ArcGIS Component Category Registrar support
        ArcGISCategoryUnregistration(registerType);

        //
        // TODO: Add any COM unregistration code here
        //
    }

    #region ArcGIS Component Category Registrar generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for ArcGIS Component Category registration -
    /// Do not modify the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private static void ArcGISCategoryRegistration(Type registerType) {
        string regKey = string.Format("HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\\CLSID\\{{{0}}}", registerType.GUID);
        MxCommandBars.Register(regKey);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for ArcGIS Component Category unregistration -
    /// Do not modify the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private static void ArcGISCategoryUnregistration(Type registerType) {
        string regKey = string.Format("HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\\CLSID\\{{{0}}}", registerType.GUID);
        MxCommandBars.Unregister(regKey);
    }

    #endregion
    #endregion

    public ContextMenu() {
        // here I want to add the items that I want, add,remove,show,hide
not the ones that are built in 

    }

    public override string Caption {
        get {
            //TODO: Replace bar caption
            return "My C# Context Menu";
        }
    }
    public override string Name {
        get {
            //TODO: Replace bar ID
            return "ContextMenu";
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I managed to create a menu using this code but I can't add items to it, and when I try to find my context menu that I created above I get value is not within range, or command not found error, as if the menu is not registered or something. Here is the code that I use in OnContextMenu

```c#
     var uid = new ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.UIDClass();
 uid.Value=""desktopExtension.ContextMenu"";-------------> error here

        IDocument document = ArcMap.Document as IDocument;
        var bars = document.CommandBars;
        var dound=bars.Find(uid) as ICommandBar;
        dound.Popup(x, y);
```

Also I tried to create the context menu as follows, but can't add items because I don't know where to get their UIDs from or how to create the Command Items

```c#
var men=commandBars.Create("TemporaryContextMenu",esriCmdBarType.esriCmdBarTypeShortcutMenu);
men.Add() // takes UID of command Item
```

I really need someone to help me with this... there are no examples online that can help me with this, the snippets don't do what I want either, they only add a context menu, and the command items are the ones built in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this figured out, the commands werent getting regestered thus they were not being foung by the command bar